# Парсинг новостей с сайта

Tags: jsoup

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи. Нужна помощь в редактировании кода для получения новостей с данного сайта https://cchgeu.ru/

```
package com.company;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * A simple example, used on the jsoup website.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://cchgeu.ru/").get();
        log(doc.title());

        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
        for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
            log("%s\n\t%s", headline.attr("title"), headline.absUrl("href"));
        }
    }

    private static void log(String msg, String... vals) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, vals));
    }
}
```

Comment: а проблема в чем?

Comment: Проблема в том, что вместо новостей у меня выходит заголовок сайта